# APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE (Contact list & Image)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console, privacy-policy

**Can someone please help me to solve this issue from play-console**

I have tried this for 4th time but still, the issue remains in play-console

We have added this thing in privacy-policy but still not succeed

[image: Throws this error again and again]
[image: Provided Contacts In What we collect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally app is live on Play store.**

In my play console, I have added a privacy-policy, but my app does not have a view to redirect privacy-policy. So I add privacy-policy in the login page and setting section, then redirected to the privacy-policy link or page. That's it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Google changed in there **term and conditions** recently they add **Data Safety** like App store doing.

According to  data safety you have to tell them your taking users  data  or not, what kind of data we are taking and what is the purpose of that data, you need to defined according to your app used.
[image]

HOW TO DO IT (Follow the steps)

Go to developer console select your app.

- go to app Content
- In side actioned tab
- Click Data Safety (Manage)
- Read Overview and go next
- And Follow the Steps and answer the all questions related to collocating data types Uses.

For more Details check this: [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#other&zippy=%2Cother-app-and-data-disclosures)